# How do I apply an array of NSSortDescriptors in a case insensitive way?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

Because [`NSHTTPCookieStorage`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/index.html) has some awful limitations I'm implementing my own and one of the methods to re-implement is [`- (NSArray *)sortedCookiesUsingDescriptors:(NSArray *)sortOrder`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSHTTPCookieStorage/sortedCookiesUsingDescriptors:). It just gets an array of `NSSortDescriptor`s and applies it but to my surprise, the results from my tests seems to indicate these sort descriptors are applied in a case insensitive fashion.

I couldn't find any way to apply `NSSortDescriptor`s in a case insensitive way other than by setting their selectors to `:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)` but since the property selector is read only, the best I managed is this:

```
NSMutableArray *insensitiveSortOrder = [NSMutableArray array];
for (NSSortDescriptor* sorter in sortOrder) {
    [insensitiveSortOrder addObject: [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: sorter.key ascending:sorter.ascending selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
}
```

Is that implementation correct? Is there a better way to achieve this?

One thing that worries me is that I'm completely ignoring the [`comparator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSSortDescriptor/comparator) property of the NSSortDescriptor.

Comment: The design contract for that method is that the caller determines the sort order. If they require case-sensitive ordering and you give them case-insensitive, then you've violated the design contract and the caller could fail in arbitrary ways. What is calling that method? If you have control over that caller, that's what you need to modify.

Comment: @KenThomases have you tested NSHTTPCookieStorage's sortedCookiesUsingDescriptors? because I wrote tests for it and it seems to sort in a case insensitive way. I'm just trying to replicate that behaviour and no, I don't have control over who calls it, it's Apple's WebView or one of its components.

Comment: @KenThomases heck, I'm not even sure if anything at all will call it, but I'm trying to provide an implementation of the cookie storage as complete and accurate as possible.